# Convert date to two days from a given date

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to convert a given date to a date that's two days ahead of the given date. My code is as follows:

```
$date = date('D, M n', strtotime('+2 days', 'Mon, Dec 31, 2012'));
```

That code sort of gets it correct. It echoes "Wed, Jan 1". It gets the name of the day and the month correct. But, not the date. I have also tried another route.

```
$d = new DateTime('Mon, Dec 31, 2012');
$d->modify('+2 days');
echo $d->format('D, M n');
```

That didn't work either. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Lance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`n` is the [format flag](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for month month.  It's saying `1` because it's in January.  Use `j` instead:

```
$d = new DateTime('Mon, Dec 31, 2012');
$d->modify('+2 days');
echo $d->format('D, M j'); //Wed, Jan 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newdate = date("D, M n",strtotime($oldDate. ' + 2 day'));
```